# Отображение даты раньше 1970

Tags: java

Имеется дата, к примеру 31.12.1950. Как с помощью класса Date сделать корректный вывод?
Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 SAMT 1950

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена! С помощью класса `Calendar` можно получить нормальное отображение даты.

Просто создаем объект:

```java
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day);
```

И потом через `getTime()` получаем `Date`.

```java
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: 1) Результат будет в часовом поясе GMT 2) С помощью класса `Calendar` можно получить массу багов.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете в конструкторе использовать отрицательные значения.
В одних сутках 86 400 000 миллисекунд.

```
Date date = new Date(-864_000_000);
```

Mon Dec 22 03:00:00 MSK 1969

Но лучше вообще не использовать класс `Date`, а пользоваться классами пакета `java.time`

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что по условию задачи необходимо использовать класс Date.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать это с помощью *только* класса `Date` вряд ли получится, понадобится как минимум `SimpleDateFormatter`, для которого надо будет установить часовой пояс `Europe/Samara`.

Смещение во времени можно подобрать вручную - грубо говоря, между 31 декабря 1950 и 1 января 1970 (началом эпохи) прошло 19 лет (из которых 5 были високосные: 1952, 1956, 1960, 1964, 1968) и 1 день, c учётом 4-часового смещения.

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Samara"));

Date old = new Date(- 3600_000L * 24 * (14 * 365 + 5 * 366) - 28 * 3600_000L);
System.out.println(sdf.format(old));
```

Вывод:

```
Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 SAMT 1950
```

---

При помощи Java Date/Time API (JSR 310) также потребуется использовать `DateTimeFormatter`, но установить дату в экземпляре `ZonedDateTime` будет гораздо проще:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeOf = ZonedDateTime.of(
    1950, 12, 31,               // дата
    0, 0, 0, 0,                 // время, включая наносекунды
    ZoneId.of("Europe/Samara")  // часовой пояс
);
System.out.println(formatter.format(zonedDateTimeOf));
// -> Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 SAMT 1950
```

Comment: но почему именно Самара? почему не Куйбышев?

Comment: но это не отвечает на мой вопрос.  Почему именно нужна Самара. Почему не другой часовой пояс?

Comment: Ваш вопрос был с подколкой про название Самары в 1950 году.  Что касается часового пояса `SAMT`, смотрите исходный вопрос, вероятно, автору было интереснее спросить про Самару, а не к примеру про Калининград в 1944.